# LiveReload not compiling SASS

Tags: haml, sass

I'm currently using the OSX app LiveReload v2.1. It watches and compiles my HAML files just fine but for some reason it doesn't seem to compile my SASS files properly. It checks my SASS files - I know because it warns me of SASS related errors upon saving. It also creates the appropriate CSS files upon saving the SASS files however, when I open the CSS files they are completely blank.

I'm a bit of a SASS n00b but I'm just trying to get any basic styling to compile down to proper CSS. For example, the following:

```
body
    background-color:blue
```

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated. Also, I should point out that I also manually installed the SASS gem, just in case, though that didn't seem to fix anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It didn't have to do with LiveReload at all, but instead how my SASS was formatted. There needed to be a space between the attribute and value. For example:

```
body
   background-color:blue
```

Should have been:

```
body
   background-color: blue
```

It would have been nice if SASS pointed this error out rather than simply spitting out an empty CSS file, oh well.